# Centering divs with imgs in custom swipe-enabled gallery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, image-gallery, android-gallery, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm not new to this forum but it's my first ever posted question. Here's what bugs me:

I'm building a custom swipe-enabled product gallery (both desktop and mobile enabled) and I'm also using jQueryUI's accordion effect. I was able to solve all issues but this one: I can't center the accordion-hidden `div` (`class="centered"`) or the elements that are inside it. Tried it all, but as soon as I add `display:table;`, the accordion effect is broken :(

The `div`s inside are all same size and `float:left` and should be able to dynamically center themselves depending on the number of elements per row.

Current CSS code:

```
.tile{
margin: 0px auto;
padding:auto;
border:none;
float:left;}

.centered{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
/*display: table;*/}
```

My complete project is here, it will be easier to understand where the catch is: http://jsfiddle.net/Fliperone/CB2fj/

The final product is visible here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fliperone/CB2fj/7/embedded/result/ <- Clicking on `Galerija` will reveal the problem :)

PS: I new to jsfiddle, I'm not sure if I set it up properly for everyone to see it, so warn me if it doesn't show.

Anyhow, thanks to everyone for this great community!

Regards

Filip

Comment: Why comment "display: table;" ? It works with display: table. The problem is when you show your div, the display becomes block, just change it.

Comment: Hi Vincent. Yes it does center the elements inside the div but it also breaks the accordion effect :( Thats exactly my problem!